# Computer going to sleep/hibernation when not wanted win 10 1909

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

My Desktop computer keeps sleeping/hibernating when ALL settings are set to never and standby (53) is all that is enabled. I have updated my display driver, monitor drivers and any others I can find.
It goes to sleep (I believe) then if left too long the monitor goes into standby and I have to reset the computer to get it to restart and continue.
Motherboard = Gigabyte H55N
Processor = Intel i5 760 @ 2.80ghz 4 core
System = x64- based PC
OS win 10 home 64bit ver 1909

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 64-bit

How to keep Windows 10 from going to sleep when all power management settings are set to never sleep:

Sleep and hibernation are not the same thing. You've taken the wrong approach.  You've assumed there is a defect instead of giving your OS a reason the stay awake.  Give your OS a reason to stay awake.

One task I do writes to memory for two hours. That activity does not prevent Windows 10 power management from applying "inactivity" rules.  If I include a periodic ping request in the task inactivity rules are not applied and the PC is not put to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wakeful](https://www.loopandkey.com/wakeful), It keeps you PC active. It's free and portable.

https://www.loopandkey.com/wakeful

[image: Wakeful Screenshot]